# Django query ForeignKey Count() zero

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have 3 tables:

**Truck** with the fields: `id`, `name`....

**Menu** with the fields: `id`, `itemname`, `id_foodtype`, `id_truck`...

**Foodtype** with the fields: `id`, `type`...

I want to get a summary like:

```
id  name              total
10  Alcoholic drink   0
5   Appetizer         11
```

My problem is to **return the results with `0` elements**.

I tried an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT
    ft.id, ft.name, COUNT(me.id) total
FROM
    foodtype ft LEFT JOIN menu me
        ON ft.id = me.id_foodtype
    LEFT JOIN truck tr
        ON tr.id = me.id_truck AND tr.id = 3
GROUP BY ft.id, ft.name
ORDER BY ft.name
```

or a **query in Django**

```
Menu.objects.filter(id_truck=3).values("id_foodtype").annotate(cnt=Count("id_foodtype"))
```

But, neither is displaying the results with `Zero` elements.

At the moment to convert this query to `Python` code, any of my queries return the exact result that I expected.
How can I return results with the `Left Join` including the `foodtypes` with zero elements in the `menu`?

Comment: this is more a question of sql-postgres than django

Comment: I edited your question to can be easier searched, in the hope that it is acceptable. I edited also my answer a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direction of LEFT JOIN depends on the object, where you start the query. If it start on `Menu` you will never see a `FoodType` unused by selected Menu items. Then is important to filter (by Truck in your case) such way that also null value Menu.id is allowed in order to can get Count == 0.

```
from django.db.models import Q
qs = (
    FoodType.objects
    .filter(Q(menu_set__id_truck=3) | Q(menu_set__id__isnull=True))
    .values()   # not necessary, but useful if you want a dict, not a Model object
    .annotate(cnt=models.Count("menu_set__id"))
)
```

**Verify:**

```
>>> print(str(qs.query))
SELECT foodtype.id, foodtype..., COUNT(menu.id) AS cnt
FROM foodtype
LEFT OUTER JOIN menu ON (foodtype.id = menu.id_foodtype)
WHERE _menu.id_truck = 3 OR menu.id IS NULL)
GROUP BY foodtype.id
```

It works with the current newest and oldest Django 2.0b1 and 1.8.

The query is the same with or without the line `.values()`. The results are dictionaries or FoodType objects with a `cnt` attribute.

---

**Footnotes**:
The name `menu_set` should be replaced by the real `related_name` of foreign key `id_foodtype` if you have defined the related_name.

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    id_foodtype = models.ForeignKey('FoodType', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                    db_column='id_foodtype', related_name='menu_set'))
    ...
```

If you start a new project I recommend to rename the foreign key to a name without "id" and the db_column field is with "id". Then `menu_item.foodtype` is a Food object and `menu_item.id_foodtype` its `id`.