# Annotation to count and return zero when there is no relation

Tags: django, django-queryset

Given the following relation:

```
class LicenseRequest:
    license_type = models.ForeignKey(LicenseType)
    created_at = models.DateField(default=now, editable=False)

class LicenseType:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)
```

I want to count how many requests have been created for each license type. However, since I am generating a graphic, I must include 0 (zero) for license types without any license request in that specific period.

I tried to do what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838375/django-query-foreignkey-count-zero), but it did not work. I can only get the count from License Types which have more than one license request.

```
qs = LicenseType.objects.filter(
                Q(licenserequest__created_at__range=(start_date, end_date)) | Q(licenserequest__isnull=True)
            ).annotate(rel_count=Count('licenserequest__id'))
```

I could find another way to achieve this goal, but I was wondering if I can do it through annotation.

I am using [django1.11.15](/questions/tagged/django1.11.15).

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0) and higher, the `Count` object has a `filter` parameter, so we can specify the conditions for this:

```
qs = LicenseType.objects.annotate(
    rel_count=Count(
        'licenserequest',
        filter=Q(licenserequest__created_at__range=(start_date, end_date))
    )
)
```

For [django-1.11](/questions/tagged/django-1.11) and below, we can use the `Sum(..)` of a `Case(..)` expression:

```
qs = LicenseType.objects.annotate(
    rel_count=Sum(Case(
        When(
            licenserequest__created_at__range=(start_date, end_date),
            then=1
        ),
        default=0,
        output_field=IntegerField()
    ))
)
```

Comment: If we filter the queryset, (ie, `LicenseType.objects.filter(...).annotate()...`), it won't reflect on **`Count()`**, right?

Comment: a much more detailed answer!

Comment: Worked like a charm. However, inn `[...] (start_date, end_date)=True` the `True` was unnecessary.

Comment: @Ev.: arrgh... yes, that was a mistake. Fixed now :)

Answer (score 2):

```
qs = LicenseType.objects.annotate(count=Count('licenserequest__id')
condition = Q(licenserequest__created_at__range=(start_date, end_date)) & Q(licenserequest__isnull=True)
qs = qs.annotate(Case(When(condition, then=F('count')), default=0, output_field=IntegerField())
```

This should work for the model description that you have provided. 
To do the later filter, you cannot use a direct .filter() but rather use a Case/When .annotate() clause