# Django complicated right-join queryset

Tags: python, django, left-join

I am trying to figure out how to solve this problem without using Raw SQL. I want to have a query set of **all provinces** categorized in  age_range, filtered by the urban area (location_type), but assume zero for provinces whose population is 0. following qs omits provinces with zero population but I want to present 0 in the sum field.

my models:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#---@desc    Keeps a list of different cities
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
class Province(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.title)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#---@desc    Keeps list of differents cities
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
class City(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province, on_delete=models.CASCADE , 
                                related_name='cities')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.province, self.title)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#---@desc    Keeps information about population records of each city
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
class Population(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name ='poeple')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER)
    number = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    location_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=LOCATION_LIST) #rural or urban area
    age = models.IntegerField(
        null=False, 
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(0),
            MaxValueValidator(100),
        ])

    objects = PopulationQuerySet.as_manager()
```

view:

```
qs= Population.objects.select_related('city__province').\
                            annotate(
                                    age_group=Case(
                                        When(age__range=(0,9), then=Value('0-9')),
                                        When(age__range=(10,19), then=Value('10-19')),
                                        When(age__range=(20,29), then=Value('20-29')),
                                        When(age__range=(30,39), then=Value('30-39')),
                                        When(age__range=(40,49), then=Value('40-49')),
                                        When(age__range=(50,59), then=Value('50-59')),
                                        When(age__range=(60,69), then=Value('60-69')),
                                        When(age__range=(70,79), then=Value('70-79')),
                                        When(age__range=(80,89), then=Value('80-89')),
                                        When(age__range=(90,99), then=Value('90-99')),
                                        When(age=100, then=Value('100+')),
                                        default=Value('100+'),
                                        output_field=CharField(),)).\
                            filter(location_type = "U").\
                            values('city__province__title', 'gender', 
                            'location_type','age_group').\
                            annotate(sum=Sum('number'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i only saw your email today, i never being through that issue, but try using Case inside your Sum to check if the population is higher than 0, if not set default value to 0.

Checkout this example

```
qs = LicenseType.objects.annotate(
    rel_count=Sum(Case(
        When(
            licenserequest__created_at__range=(start_date, end_date),
            then=1
        ),
        default=0,
        output_field=IntegerField()
    ))
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52290986
)