# Django group by Choice Field and COUNT Zeros

Tags: python, django, django-models, group-by, django-orm

Consider the following django model:

```
class Image(models.Model):
image_filename = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Rating(models.Model):
DIMENSIONS = [
    ('happy', 'happiness'),
    ('competence', 'competence'),
    ('warm_sincere', 'warm/sincere'),
]
rating_value = models.IntegerField(),
rating_dimension = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=DIMENSIONS),
image = models.ForeignKey(Image, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now, I'd like to group all Ratings by the number of ratings per category like this:

```
Rating.objects.values("rating_dimension").annotate(num_ratings=Count("rating_value"))
```

which returns a QuerySets like this:

```
[{'rating_dimension': 'happy', 'num_ratings': 2},
 {'rating_dimension': 'competence', 'num_ratings': 5}]
```

Is there a way to include all not-rated dimensions? To achieve an output like:

```
[{'rating_dimension': 'happy', 'num_ratings': 2},
{'rating_dimension': 'competence', 'num_ratings': 5},
{'rating_dimension': 'warm_sincere', 'num_ratings': 0}] # ← zero occurrences should be included.
```

Comment: Not really, but you only have 3 choices so you could either simply make 3 queries or find out which dimension was not rated and add an entry with 0 yourself (you can use loops if more choices).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat There are certainly ways to this via the ORM. Check out e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52290430/annotation-to-count-and-return-zero-when-there-is-no-relation#answer-52290986)

Comment: @schwobaseggl that is for a relation, Check the question it is for a CharField with choices.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat You are right. If there is no `Rating` with a particular choice, the db can't possibly produce it. Your second suggestion is the way to go in order to avoid spurious db hits.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks for the comment, yes, a for loop is of course possible, I just thought that there has to be a nicer way and the example shows just 3 of actual +20 dimensions…

Comment: @FlavourDave If you don't mind I'll put an answer that uses loops and is quite small and simple?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat sure, that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we will create a dictionary with counts for all dimensions initialised  to 0.

```
results = {dimension[0]: 0 for dimension in Rating.DIMENSIONS}
```

Next we will query the database:

```
queryset = Rating.objects.values("rating_dimension").annotate(num_ratings=Count("rating_value"))
```

Next we will update our results dictionary:

```
for entry in queryset:
    results.update({entry['rating_dimension']: entry['num_ratings']})
```

In the template we can iterate over this dictionary by `{% for key, value in results.items %}`. Or the dictionary can be converted to any suitable structure as per need in the views.