# Django model with Charfield Count and Zero values

Tags: python, django

I have a Django database model that has some attributes, one of them is a Charfield 'category' with Choices.
I now want to annotate a queryset of this model with the count of the rows of each category. The thing is, the way i know to do it, only categories present in the queryset are getting counted, but i want a queryset with all categories annotated with the count (0 if no rows with this category).

This is what im doing at the moment:

```
Model.objects.all().values('category').annotate(total=Count('category'))
```

Is there a way to display all categories, including such with count 0?

Comment: Well exactly how would you count `Category`s that do not exist?

Comment: If the choices are fixed and you do not feel the need to create another model, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65960619/14991864) by me on a similar question.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: well one of my professors once said: "there are only three sensical constants in programming: zero, one, and many". He meant that typically setting things to a fixed cardinality eventually results in a lot of trouble :). It typically also will yield extra problems like *data duplication* since now we repeat the same category in every record. If we later want to rename the category, it can create a serious headache.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem great advice there. :) Never thought of it that way. The method in above answer was also actually created by me due to a similar problem I once had, now that I look back it was bad design on my part.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: well +1 anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not count categories that do not exist, since, well... these do not exist. The `choices` are not even transferred to the database.

Using a `CharField` with `choices` is not the ideal modeling for this. Typically it is better to make a model `Category` and then another `MyModel` with [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) to link a `MyModel` object to a `Category`, so:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class MyModel(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

then we can create categories like:

```
Category.objects.bulk_create(
    Category(name='technology'),
    Category(name='art'),
    Category(name='science')
)
```

if we then link `MyModel` objects to these `Category`s, we can annotate the `Category` with the number of `MyModel`s with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Category.objects.annotate(
    num_mymodel=Count('mymodel')
)
```

Here the `Category`s that arise from *this* queryset will have an extra attribute `.num_mymodel` with the number of linked `MyModel` objects. Since a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is performed, for `Category`s without any `MyModel`s, it will use `0`.

Comment: Yep, thanks. I guess its better to have everything in a model.