# Django Regroup how to have an arbitrary order

Tags: django, formset

I have a model formset that contains the model, Items. Each Item is given a category: 'Produce','Grains','Protein/Dairy','Extra Items' and I want it to display in the html in that order. How can I do that?

Comment: Is category a `CharField` with `choices`? If so change it to a foreign key with a new model. If it already is a foreign key (or you just added this new model) add some field for ordering to this foreign key model and order the queryset with respect to this ordering field.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I was hoping there was a more efficient way with Django's regroup https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup

Comment: Regroup needs your objects to be ordered, giving rise to your problem. The solution I suggested is in fact more efficient and better design. I once received great advice from a fellow user [@Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66612100/django-model-with-charfield-count-and-zero-values?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment117754147_66612100). "there are only three sensical constants in programming: zero, one, and many". Check the link for a more in depth explanation :). Otherwise you can only make a custom template tag to order your result this way.

Comment: Unfortunately, in addition to category, I also have storage type... it gets complicated if I made a new model with a foreign key for that...